# How can I build with Babel (while preserving the source's folder structure) with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a project with a hierarchy something like this:

`-src/
    -app.js (only accesses server-side code)
    -server/
        -models/
        -routes/
        ...
    -client/
        -views/
        -scss/
            -style1.scss
            -style2.scss
            ...
        -js/
            -index.js (es6)
            -other-page.js (es6)
            ...
        ...
-.babelrc
-package.json
-webpack.config.js
...`

and I want Webpack to copy everything within src, replacing .js files with Babel-compiled equivalents, and replacing .scss files with compiled CSS. Like this:

`-dist/
    -app.js
    -server/
        -models/
        -routes/
        ...
    -client/
        -views/
        -css/
            -style1.css
            -style2.css
        -js/
            -index.js (now compiled)
            -other-page.js (now compiled)
        ...
...`

There are non-js files within `src/server/`, so I don't think it's possible to combine everything inside of it into app.js. Still, any help would be appreciated regarding my question.

Answer (score 1):

Webpack may be the wrong tool for the job. It is self-described as being a `module bundler` so its feature-set is very strictly focused towards that end: bundling things together. I think gulp would be better for something like this.

But however, what is your reason for wanting to do this?

As an aside: if you really had to do it this way, you may be able to do it with [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin), which is able to copy files and folders to other destinations. There is a `transform` property that the plugin accepts where you can pass in a function. I can't readily think of how it would work, but perhaps you can do something there. Again, I don't know why you would need to implement it precisely this way though.